# PGFPlots / TikzPicture two corresponding diagrams with changing radius

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have totally no idea how to achieve the following two diagrams in Latex.
I have done a lot of work with tikzpicture but none of my projects included something like this.

The right diagram represents the radius of the "circles" in the left diagram. The right diagram shows two or more circles with changed radius for every degree. So its not an "even circle".

[image: Two Diagrams]
Tikzpgf Manual: https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf

**Problems:**

1. How to draw these "circles"
2. How to link the two diagrams?

I appreciate any type of help!

Greetings from Bavaria
Pascal

Comment: Hi, welcome. Is there any specific relation between the angle and the radius? I.e., do you have functions for r(theta)?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use a parametric plot.  See [variable=\t] in the pgfplots manual (\addplot option).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No. The only thing that I need is that the radius is changing within one rotation (2pi). One "circle" need to end with a larger radius at 2pi and one with a smaller radius at 2pi.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: The version of the TikZ manual you refer to is very old, so unless your system is also very old, it's likely outdated. You may have documentation installed along with the packages, which you can find by opening a terminal/command prompt, and entering `texdoc pgf` (to get the pgf/TIkZ manual). Otherwise, find the latest version on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or texdoc.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by John Kormylo in a comment, you can use parametric plots with `pgfplots` to make that. Define an appropriate function that describes the radius as a function of angle, and use

```
\addplot (
          {<function that describes the x-component>},
          {<function that describes the y-component>}
         );
```

Here, because I defined functions for r(θ), the normal parameterization is x = r * cos(θ) and y = r * sin(θ). Note that the trigonometric functions of `pgf` use degrees, so if you input radians that has to be converted to degrees.

For the second plot you just use `\addplot {r(x)};`, where `r` is some function defined previously.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
   % define a style that lets you place an arrow on a path
   arrow on path/.style={
     decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position #1 with \arrow{>}
        },
     postaction=decorate
  },
  % set the default position of the arrow head to 10% along the path
  arrow on path/.default=0.1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
% define the functions that give the relationship between
% the angle and the radius here
% pgf trig functions assume degrees by default, hence the
% conversion to degrees with deg(..)
declare function={
  r0(\x) = 0.1 - 0.01*\x;
  r1(\x) = 0.5 + 0.07*\x + 0.08*sin(deg(\x));
  r2(\x) = 1;
  }
]

% a groupplot is a collection of axes organized in a grid
\begin{groupplot}[
  % set the size of the grid
  group style={group size=2 by 1},
  % default options for both axes:
  % style of axis
  axis lines=center,
  % default domain to plot and number of samples to calculate in that domain
  domain=0:2*pi,
  samples=50,
  % 
  enlargelimits=0.1,
  % set default options for all plots
  every axis plot/.append style={
    very thick,
    no markers
    }
]
\nextgroupplot[
   % define labels for the x- and y-axis
   xlabel=$x$,
   ylabel=$y$,
   % use same unit vectors for x and y, so a circle looks like a circle
   axis equal,
   % define which values to place ticks on the axes, and which labels to use
   ytick=\empty,
   xtick={0.1, 0.5, 1},
   xticklabels={$r_0$, $r_1$, $r_2$},
]

% make parametric plots with x = r * cos(theta) and y = r * sin(theta)
% I used the default plotting variable name x for theta
  \addplot +[arrow on path=0.2] ({r0(x)*cos(deg(x))}, {r0(x)*sin(deg(x))});
  \addplot +[arrow on path] ({r1(x)*cos(deg(x))}, {r1(x)*sin(deg(x))});
  \addplot +[arrow on path] ({r2(x)*cos(deg(x))}, {r2(x)*sin(deg(x))});
  


\nextgroupplot[
  xlabel={$\theta$},
  ylabel={$r$},
  ytick={0.1, 0.5, 1},
  yticklabels={$r_0$, $r_1$, $r_2$},
  xtick={2*pi},
  xticklabels={$2\pi$}
]

% plot the radii as functions of the angle
  \addplot {r0(x)};
  \addplot {r1(x)};
  \addplot {r2(x)};

  \draw [dashed] (2*pi,0) -- (2*pi, 1.1);

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thats incredible! Thank you so much! Is there a way to pay you a pizza or a coffee? :)

Comment: @Pascal No, but no need either :)